# MVC Spring Controller, display dbData in HTML file

Tags: java, html, database, spring, model-view-controller

If I write a Spring MVC Controller, how can I display the DBData in my HTML file.

e.g. I have db.table called Setting and I want to display the IDs from that table in my HTML file as a Dropdown list.

```
 @Controller
public class CustomChannelController {

    private Setting setting;
    private Diagram diagram;
    private Channel channel;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customchannel", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody Setting getId() {
        return this.setting;
    }
```

---

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="col-md-12 control-label"> <%=language['UI.reportSetting.channel']%> : </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="selectReportChannel" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" ><%=setting[ID]%></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you retrieve data... do you use AJAX calls? Or do you need them when page is loaded?

Let's see the 2 scenarios 
Note: in boths scenarios we assume you are returning a list of object like this:

```
public class Option{
  private String value;
  private String text;
  //getter and setter
}
```

**AJAX CALL**: for this I assume we are using JQuery; in this case you will have in your JS or JSP file something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'customchannel',
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    type : 'GET',

    success : function(items) {
        $.each(items, function (i, item) {
            $('#selectReportChannel').append($('<option>', { 
                value: item.value,
                text : item.text 
         }));
        });
    },
    error : function(data) {

    }
});


<select id="selectReportChannel" class="form-control">
</select>
```

**Page loaded** In this case in your controller who will render the HTML page you can do something like this:

```
 @Controller
public class CustomChannelController {

    private Setting setting;
    private Diagram diagram;
    private Channel channel;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/customchannel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getId(Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.add("options", this.setting);
        return new ModelAndView("yourPage", uiModel) ;
    }
```

Then in the HTML page you can use JSTL in this way:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="col-md-12 control-label"> <%=language['UI.reportSetting.channel']%> : </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="selectReportChannel" class="form-control">
                <c:forEach items="${options}" var="option">
            <option value="${option.value}">${option.text}</option>
        </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a solution. First a need to create a Spring MVC Controller then a Service and link then the Controller to the Backbone model file.